# Realm insertion and updation crashes after some time

Tags: ios, database, realm

I'm using Realm as my backend and it is working properly but after sometime as continue using the app it gets crashes rising the message in console as

```
**[RLMRealmConfiguration copy]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fdea71dfa70**
```

As in my app the insertion , deletion or updation done after a specifice time interval and this error don't go to the point where it get crashed after using the exception break point also. 
Thanks.

Comment: Is this crash something that you're able to reproduce? If so, I'd suggest running your app in Instruments using the Zombies instrument, which should tell you how your app came to be messaging a deallocated object.

Comment: Ok @bdash Thanks. I'll look in to it.